# Basic derivation question

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So I had 4 or five calculus classes a couple years ago, and I find myself not being able to remember a thing.

Consider the problem

$\dfrac{d}{dx} \dfrac{1}{(1+x)^2}$

I rewrite this as

$\dfrac{d}{dx} (x+1)^{-2}$

but here, why am I allowed to do this:

$ = (-2)(x+1)^{-3} \dfrac{d}{dx}(x+1)$

It seems like a chain rule, but I can't recall a chain rule being used in this context (I thought it was for problems where you need the derivative of a product)

Comment: The chain rule is for "composite functions".. i.e.  you example above we could rewite your function as: $u(x) = (1+x), y = u^{-2}$ and then say $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx}$  There are product rules and quotient rules, but those are not in play in this example.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the change in variables $$y = 1+x$$

if $f = (1+x)^{-2} = y^{-2} $ then the chain rule states that:

$$ \frac{{\rm d}f}{{\rm d}x} =\frac{{\rm d}f}{{\rm d}y} \frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x} = \left(\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}y} y^{-2} \right) \left( 1\right) = (-2) y^{-3} = -\frac{2}{y^3} = -\frac{2}{(1+x)^3}$$

Answer (score 0):

It is the use of the derivation formula $(x^n) = n x^{n-1}$, and also the derivation rule of composite function. (because of it the $\dfrac{d}{dx}(x+1)$ term).

(And yes, it is called the chain rule. In the more general case $((f(x))^n)' = n (f(x))^{n-1} \cdot f'(x) $)

Answer (score 0):

Let me remind you a small trick which I find very useful when facing expressions which contain only products, quotients and powers : [logarithmic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_differentiation).

Applied to your case $$y=\dfrac{1}{(1+x)^2}\implies \log(y)=-2\log(1+x)$$ Differentiate both sides $$\frac{y'}y=-2 \frac 1 {1+x}\implies y'=-2 \frac y {1+x}=\frac{-2}{(1+x)^3}$$ Using it, you will easily find, if needed, the derivative of $u(x)\,v(x)$, $\frac{u(x)}{v(x)}$ ,$\frac{u^a(x)}{v^b(x)}$ and so on.

Let us consider the last case $$y=\frac{u^a(x)}{v^b(x)}\implies \log(y)=a \log(u)-b \log(v)$$ Differentiate both sides $$\frac{y'}y=a\frac {u'}u-b\frac {v'}v=\frac{au'v-buv'}{uv}\implies y'=y\frac{au'v-buv'}{uv}$$ that is to say $$y'=(au'v-buv')\frac{u^{a-1}}{v^{b+1}}$$